# Simple field extension in extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Task: let $K$ be an extension of field $F$. Show, that $K$ include simple extension of field $F$.

I denote $K^{'}$ as simple field extension of field $F$. Definition of simple field extension:
if $\exists c \in K^{'}\setminus F$ that $K^{'} = F(c)$.

I think that simple extension of field should be the smallest, so I rewrote it as $K^{'} = \cap \{K^{'}<K: c \in K^{'}, F \subset K^{'}\}$, so $K^{'} \subseteq K$, where $[K^{'}:F]$ - is random.

Is it correct?

Comment: Huh?  $F$ is an extension of $F$ and there does not exist such a $c$.

Comment: @user10354138 how come? I wrote definition of simple field extension.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_extension

Comment: @Aleksandra: Under your definition, $F$ is not a simple extension because there are no elements in $F\setminus F$ that you can pick. Your definition is incorrect; it should not *require* $c\notin F$. And your definition of $K’$ is nonsense: you have $K’$ on both sides of the equation, and $c$ is a free variable which does not mean anything.

Comment: As it stands, the task is trivially simple: pick an arbitrary $c\in K$. Then $K’=F(c)$ is a simple extension of $F$ contained in $K$.